# Updating a view whenever there's new records with Ember-Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

I have a simple Ember.js app. There's an `application view` and inside that view there's a `results view`.

I'm using ember-model to fetch JSON from the server that way:

```
Map.Winery = Ember.Model.extend({
    name:          Ember.attr(),
    address:       Ember.attr(),
    address_2:     Ember.attr(),
    city:          Ember.attr(),
    stateprovince: Ember.attr(),
    country:       Ember.attr(),
    latitude:      Ember.attr(),
    longitude:     Ember.attr(),

    full_address: function () {
        return this.get('address') + ' ' + this.get('city') + ' ' + this.get('stateprovince') + ' ' + this.get('country');
    }.observes('address', 'city', 'stateprovince', 'country')
});

Map.Winery.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create({
    findAll: function(klass, records) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/api/wineries').then(function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                records.load(klass, response.data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I made it as simple as possible so people can have a fair look at what's going on.

So basically, I have a button in my application view that whenever I click, calls an action that calls Map.Winery.findAll(); (reloads data from the server).

What I'd like is, whenever there's new data loaded in the records, the `results view` should update with the new results.

**application.hbs**

```
<button class="locate" {{action "reload" on="click"}}>Reload</button>
{{view Map.ResultsView}}
```

**application_controller.js**

```
Map.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        reload: function() {
            var results = Map.Winery.findAll();
        }
    }
});
```

**results.hbs**

```
<div class="results">
    {{#each results}}
        <p>{{this}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

**results_view.js**

```
Map.ResultsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'results',

    didInsertElement: function(e) {
    }

});
```

Now question is: How do I make it so whenever there's new data loaded from the server to the records, results view gets updated?

I tried inserting as much related code as possible, feel free to ask any questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found is to add an event to whatever I need to be triggered and use that trigger whenever I need it.

Using `Ember.Evented`:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    viewUpdated: function(args) {} 
    /* controller stuff here */ 
});
```

I'm now able to add events like this from almost anywhere:

```
this.get('controller').on('viewUpdated', $.proxy(this.viewUpdated, this));
```

So whenever I have to trigger the view to update I do:

```
this.get('controllers.application').trigger('viewUpdated', args);
```

(args is optional by the way)

That way the event gets triggered whenever I want to. It's not as powerful as an observer but still it does the job pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

Just push the new objects into your collection (or replace the collection with the new collection from findAll).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EFiTOtu/1/edit

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    addNewColor: function(){
      this.get('model').pushObject(this.get('newColor'));
    }
  }
});
```